# What IR codes are emitted by Faber/AEG/Franke/Smeg... RC?

Tags: communication, infrared

What infra-red codes are emitted by the depicted* [remote control](http://www.smeguk.com/product/rckf/) used by many hood manufactures (Faber/Mepamsa, AEG, Franke, Smeg, Airlux...)?

Identifying the manufacturer of the remote control / IR chip could be enough. It could be listed in lirc, irdb... IR codes repositories (hood manufactures are not listed there).

[image: remote control]

* I do not have the device, otherwise I would record the codes.

The goal is that the Smart hob can inform the hub the frying has started, but I do not know the IR codes to start the hood. The RC is quite expensive, so I rather tried to ask first.

Comment: This question is very probably off topic (I really can't see a IoT angle here)

Comment: @hardillb I suppose the OP might be using an internet-connected IR hub like a [Logitech Harmony](https://www.logitech.com/en-gb/product/harmony-hub) and is hoping to control the devices through that (which would necessitate knowing the codes). Is that the case, @Jan? That said, I'm not sure whether anyone here will be able to help given that it's a particularly niche area; by far the easiest way would simply be to buy a remote and test it.

Comment: @Aurora0001, you are correct. Smart hob can inform the hub the frying has started, but I do not know the IR codes to start the hood. The RC is quite expensive, so I rather tried to ask at first. Thank you.

Comment: @JanMolnar, I am also trying to solve this problem. I actually own this remote (Faber) and tried to teach the codes from it to Logitech Harmony, but with no luck. I contacted Logitech support and they said the codes looked "weird" (too short) for IR codes and that they would be able to upload correct codes if I had them.  So Now I am trying to get actual code specifications from Faber support but with no luck so far. Did not know  this remote is used by other manufacturers as well. Maybe will try to reach out to them.

Comment: Still no luck with getting the IR codes for this remote. One of the companies wrote me it is "secret".

This is how the remote looks inside: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IrH0.jpg it reads "PCB0602-8101-001V3.0" and  "XWD-0039".

Comment: This is in the class of things which is *trivial* to determine if you have the device is hand, and all but impossible if you do not. One might fairly ask what the goal here is: if this is for personal use, the question seems irrelevant since you have no need to detect something you do not have.  While if this is a commercial project, your business side needs to have budgeted for basic research requirements, like buying the products you hope to inter-operate with... That leaves the possibility of an open source project, in which case, find a clueful user with the device and get their help.

Comment: Since the question was asked, I found Faber on [Open Connectivity Foundation members list](https://openconnectivity.org/foundation/membership-list), so I tried to ask for the codes once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Light toggle:

```
&\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0018\u0017\u0018\u00170-\u0018\u0017\u0018\u00170[\u0019\u0016\u0018\u0017H\u0000\r\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
```

Fan toggle:

```
&\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0018\u0016\u0019-1\u0016\u0018\u0017\u0018-1D\u0019-\u0018\u00170\u0000\r\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
```

Captured with a https://www.ibroadlink.com/rmPro+/ and https://github.com/momodalo/broadlinkjs

Hope that helps, I've not yet found if there's a secret separate 'on' to 'off' switch, toggling really sucks when trying to connect up to home automation

Comment: Thank you. More codes (fan intensity...) are welcome.

Comment: @JanMolnar is the format useful/meaningful? if so happy to repeat with with the other buttons

Comment: I do not understand `&`, `[`, `\r`, `H`, `-`, `-1`, `-1D` parts, but I believe they are explained somewhere. I saw some scripts to convert irdb format (preferred to me) to this, so the opposite way should be also possible. I believe even the other codes would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: @JanMolnar it's binary encoded. I've taken down the rig for the minute while we're faffing with re-arranging the kitchen. I'll capture the rest when its done. let me know if there's a better/preferred format and I'll try and capture/encode to that

Comment: @chrisns Is it possible to convert it to a LIRC file?

Comment: @fbart almost certainly, no idea and no personal need to do it. I have faith in you that you can do it though! :)